# Why is the top bar not changed on Stack Exchange, Area 51 and Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, top-bar, stackexchange.com

[Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/), [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com)<sup>1</sup> still show the old bar.

<sub>1 See [Why does Ask Ubuntu have a special Top Bar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210397/why-does-ask-ubuntu-have-a-special-top-bar)</sub>

Comment: So does [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) but not [Discuss Area51](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Area 51 uses an old, heavily modified version of Stack Exchange. This is probably why. Don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Emracool. And *Discuss Area51* does not?

Comment: @juergend *Area 51 Discussions* uses rev 2013.12.6.1206 (same as Stack Overflow and probably the other sites), *Area 51* uses rev 2013.12.2.190, *Stack Exchange* uses rev 2013.12.6.740

Comment: And then there's askubuntu

Comment: @3ventic - see [Why does Ask Ubuntu have a special Top Bar?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210397/why-does-ask-ubuntu-have-a-special-top-bar)

Comment: @Wikis Thanks, although, I was already aware of the reasons

Comment: Ask Ubuntu has it now, so this is STATUS-SEMI-COMPLETED.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It will be, just haven't gotten there yet.  Implementing it on other code bases is trickier and involves some duplication.  We want to make sure it's exactly how we want it on the main Q&A engine before duplicating anything to the other sites, as that potentially means fixing `n` things rather than 1 down the road.  Also, there are a few APIs and such to build.