# Why does Ask Ubuntu have a special Top Bar?

Tags: discussion, top-bar, askubuntu

I was looking at how the new top bar looks on every Stack Exchange and I wondered.

Why do the Linux enthusiasts have a different top bar unique of all Stack Exchange websites ?

> [image]

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7761/652.

Comment: How much time did it take you to look through 112 sites?:)

Comment: @ike Skipped the beta sites.

Answer (score 9):

The [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) top bar ties in with the Canonical sites and their design, as it has for quite a long time now - this site has had a *different* top bar since the Canonical redesign.

The new bar will go in, but the exact design and integration have not been completed, as it is not as easy to integrate it into the Canonical look and feel.

Comment: Great wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: And yet you settle on black for every site... :-P I know how hard it must be, but meh...

Comment: @Doorknob - I can't speak for the team who worked on the bar, but I *do* believe it will be black. The current askubuntu bar is very custom and integrating the new bar will happen, but can't be _exactly_ the same as other sites due to this customization. As far as I know, it will have the same design - it is more about **where** it will be located and **how** to achieve it.

Comment: One [suggestion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7761/what-will-be-the-new-bar-for-ask-ubuntu#comment13566_7762) from andrewsomething: Put a gap between the two bars, with the Canonical bar above as it currently is, and the new SE bar below **the same width as the page content** instead of full width.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen - don't know _what_ we will go with, but either way, it will require special casing.